# How to do IN query with a python tuple

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to do the following query:

```
people = ('mike', 'dave', 'andrew')
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE person IN %s', people)
```

However, this raises a SQL exception. What would be the correct formatting for using an `IN *python tuple()*` in mysql?

Comment: try `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE person IN %s', (people,))` since it expects a list for the second item ... and you want your list to be the first item of that tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sql_stmt = 'SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE person IN (%s)' % ','.join(map(str,people))

cursor.execute(sql_stmt)
```